# Nuxt.js axios request cached inside asyncData after deployment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, caching, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Why axios requests will be cached after deployment? I've deploy my nuxt.js project with command **nuxt generate** and when share my project to shared hosting and refresh the page then post updates or new comments to post not showed. I make axios request inside `asyncData` method.

**Code:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  async asyncData({ req, params }) {
    let [post, comments] = await Promise.all([
      axios.get(`/post/${id}`),
      axios.get(`/post/${id}/comments`),
    ])

    return {
       post: post.data,
       comments: comments.data
    }
  }
}
```

How I can make axios request which not will be cached generaly in Nuxt.js?

Comment: It's not necessarily axios or Nuxt.js that caches your data. It can also be the server - in that case you have to modify server cache settings.

Comment: When I generate my project with command `nuxt generate` the nuxt.js will generate static html files which can be shared to hosting. In my case I don't use `node.js` server @muka.gergely